# Show home in breadcrumb navgation in Document Library in My Site in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, breadcrumbs

The breadcrumb in the document library in My Sites shows:
user name > Document Library name

Is it possible to change it to "Home > User name > Document Library name"
or "Home > Document Library Name"

What is the easiest way to achieve this?
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

If it's a public MySite, I would suggest creating a new Custom Master Page from the Default Master and modifying the HTML directly. This can be achieved by opening the site using SharePoint Designer - after creating the new Master Page, set it as the the Default Custom.

Answer (score -2):

In your MySite site settings, go to "Portal Site Connection" and set your home name and URL.

To do it for all your my site, you'll need both:

- To script the operation for all existing mysites (easy in PowerShell)
- Use feature stapling to do it for all new mysites : http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/03/22/customizing-moss-2007-my-sites-within-the-enterprise.aspx

**Edit: (precision as I'm beeing downvoted) This is as far as you can get.**

Comment: the portal connection is in the upper left corner, this doesn't solve the problem.